# iptables and multiple ports

Tags: iptables, linux-networking

This doesn't work for me:

```
# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dports 110,143,993,995 -j ACCEPT

iptables v1.4.7: unknown option `--dports'
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

However in the man page, there is an option `--dports`... any ideas?

Comment: Quick guess would be that you need to use the multiport module: `-m multiport --dports 110,143,993,995 ...`

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You have to use `--match multiport` in the rule for defining more ports

```
#iptables -A INPUT -p tcp  --match multiport --dports 110,143,993,995 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 14):

You need to specify the -m multiport module before using the dports options