# What is the correct way to open a range of ports in iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking

I have come across articles advising for the following:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp 1000:2000 -j ACCEPT
```

And others stating that the above will not work and iptables only supports multiple port declarations with the `--multiport` option.

Is there a correct way to open many ports with iptables?

Comment: Related question: [iptables and multiple ports](http://serverfault.com/q/353130/4276)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

This is the correct way:

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --match multiport --dports 1024:3000 -j ACCEPT`

As an example. Source [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-iptables-multiport-range/).

Comment: If you don't know the state of the ruleset `-I` is somewhat safer than `-A`.

Comment: @Iain, could you please explain the reasoning behind that?

Comment: @jayhendren many rulesets will have a default drop everything rule e.g. `-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited` at the end of the INPUT and other tables. Using `-A` adds the rule at the end of the table, after the final rule so it won't ever be considered as netfilter works on a first match wins basis. Using `-I` inserts the rule at the beginning of the table ans as such it will always be considered.

Comment: @Iain however, some rulesets also have rules at the beginning that filter or ratelimit packets, so it's worthwhile to point out that `-I` isn't *always* safer if you don't know the ruleset.

Comment: @jayhendren I think you just did and also note I said somewhat not _always_.

Answer (score 81):

What you've been told is right, although you've written it wrong (you've forgotten `--dport`).

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1000:2000` will open up inbound traffic to TCP ports 1000 to 2000 inclusive.

`-m multiport --dports` is only needed if the range you want to open is not continuous, eg `-m multiport --dports 80,443`, which will open up HTTP and HTTPS **only** - not the ones in between.

Note that the ordering of rules is important, and (as Iain alludes to in his comment elsewhere) it's your job to make sure that any rule you add is in a place where it will be effective.

Comment: I could allude here as well if you want ;)

Comment: Hee hee hee!  Go on, then, the message is worth repeating!

Comment: This is the correct answer; it is more thorough.

Answer (score 15):

TL;DR but...

Pure port range without multiport module:
`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1000:2000 -j ACCEPT`

Equivalent multiport example:
`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 1000:2000 -j ACCEPT`

...and variation about multi port with multi ranges (yes, this is also possible):
`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 1000,1001,1002:1500,1501:2000 -j ACCEPT`

...and equivalent multi port multi range example with negation:
`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport ! --dports 0:999,2001:65535 -j ACCEPT`

Have phun.

Answer (score 1):

According to man iptables-extensions you can define a port range just by using the --dport switch.

**tcp**
These extensions can be used if `--protocol tcp' is specified. It provides the following options:
[!] --destination-port,--dport port[:port]

Destination port or port ***range specification***.  The flag --dport is a convenient alias for this option.

So this is also specifying a port range:
`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1000:2000 -j ACCEPT`

Answer (score 1):

there is an other way to add the entry directly on the Iptables file.
location `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 1024:3000 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

after that restart iptable service

Comment: If you only use `NEW` state, only the first packets are accepted.
You can use `NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED` to allow incoming requests for the port range

Answer (score -2):

Add '$> iptables -L --line-numbers' to verify your rules and rule order. You can optionally edit the config file(s) and make corrections (then restart iptables), e.g. edit /etc/iptables/rules.v4/6

Comment: this does not answer the question "correct way to open a range of ports in iptables"